# Sending SNS push through lambda - no message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-lambda

I have a problem with my lambda function. It takes the data of the devices and sends the push notification (information that someone added you to friends). However, it often happens that the push notificaiton is not sent. Sometimes, I have to activate the function couple of times (through simultaneous clicking on the button) to make it send push notifications. When testing the below function in Lambda it does not send any push notifications. What might be the issue?

Thank you in advance,
John

```
console.log("Loading friend-request function");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var senderID = event.senderID;
    var receiverID = event.receiverID;
    var message = event.message;

    var eventText = JSON.stringify(event);
    console.log("Received event:", eventText);
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    var params = {
        Message: message, 
        Subject: "Test SNS From Lambda",
        TargetArn: receiverID
    };

    context.succeed(message); 
    sns.publish(params, context.done);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the `sns.publish()` function is asynchronous, i.e. you must wait for it to complete before you can call the `context.succeed()`. Otherwise, the Lambda function may terminate before the message has been published.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // same as before...

    var params = {...}

    // do not call context.succeed() yet

    sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to publish SNS message');
            context.fail(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('SNS message published successfully');
            context.succeed(data);
        }
    });
};
```